# Why is the web page not loading until i exit the node instance with ctrl+c?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am working on a node.js project and I have created a http server. It incudes mapping values from API into the html page and sending it back as a response. But when I run the server with 'nodemon app.js' command, the page in the browser keeps on loading without any output until I exist the running app.js process with ctrl+c.
Below is what the server code looks like:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url == "/") {
        request(
            "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Bhubaneswar&appid=ee6cc6680b9ce81b7df5332b412c5cff"
            ).on('data', (chunk) => {
                const objectData = JSON.parse(chunk);
                const arrData = [objectData];
                const realTimeData = arrData.map((val) => replaceVal(home, val)).join();
                res.write(realTimeData);
            }).on('end', () => {
                res.end();
            });
    }
});
```

I also want to point out that the realTimeData does contain the correct html code when executed. I just want to understand what is causing the page to just continue loading without sending the response back to the browser.

Appreciate the help!!!

- I tried replacing res.write(realTimeData) with res.end(realTimeData).

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the data before sending:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
request(
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Bhubaneswar&appid=ee6cc6680b9ce81b7df5332b412c5cff"
    ).on('data', (chunk) => {
        const objectData = JSON.parse(chunk);
        const arrData = [objectData];
        // const realTimeData = arrData.map((val) => replaceVal(home, val)).join();
        res.write(JSON.stringify(arrData));
    }).on('end', () => {
        res.end();
    });
```

})